# Need to make a 4D plot (3D + Colour)

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surf

I need to make a 3D surface where colour will represent the fourth variable. I know "surf" is SIMILAR to what I need, but that did not work fine. Basically my data obtained from photododie sensor scanning along x,y,z and the forth variable is the intensity( data). The data are stored in text files in the following order.

Total files=2380
in each file there are 4 columns and 480 rows. the columns represent x,y,z,data

I was trying to plot the 3D surface but got this error " Error using
matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface/set
Value must be a vector or 2D array of numeric
type". Please help

Here is the code

```
close all;

close all;

Axstep=2.5; %  scanning with 2.5 micron step along x and y directions

Axlines=2380; %number of text files( in each file there are 4 column of equal 

sized data (x,y,z,data) and 480 rows)

Path = 'C:\Users\asay0001\Google Drive\matlab\exp2_27-11-17_CONF09\all data - Copy';

Data = zeros(480,Axlines); % 480 rows in one file out of 2380


for i = 1:Axlines

DataTemp = importdata([Path '\DATA (' num2str(i) ').txt']);

Data(:,i) = DataTemp(:,4); % read column 4 which represents data to be ploted

end

[x y,z] = meshgrid([-3200:2.5:-2602.5],[325:2.5:672.5],[-800:100:800]);

surf(x,y,z,Data')
```

Comment: Look into the command [`patch`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html).

Comment: I think you should be trying to visualize slices of your data cube instead of using surf for the whole cube. Did you see https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/visualizing-four-dimensional-data.html?